# reactjs cant passing props to latitude and longitude (google map)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, axios, react-props

i cannot passing this props to langitude and longitude from google map. i want to put them a value from api data.

error
[image]

heres the code

```
import { GoogleMap } from "react-google-maps";
import React from "react";

export default function Goomap(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <GoogleMap
        defaultZoom={10}
        defaultCenter={{
          lat: props.result.location.coordinates.latitude,
          lng: props.result.location.coordinates.longitude
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

import React from "react";
import { withScriptjs, withGoogleMap } from "react-google-maps";
import Goomap from "./goomap";
const WrappedMap = withScriptjs(withGoogleMap(Goomap));

class MapGoogle extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div style={{ width: "30vw", height: "100vh" }}>
          <WrappedMap
            googleMapURL={`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&libraries=geometry,drawing,places&key=${process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_KEY}`}
            loadingElement={<div style={{ height: "100%" }} />}
            containerElement={<div style={{ height: "100%" }} />}
            mapElement={<div style={{ height: "100%" }} />}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default MapGoogle;


import React from "react";
import DataListItem from "../feature/datalist";
import Axios from "axios";
import MapGoogle from "./gmap";

class Data extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      results: [],
      loading: true
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    Axios.get("https://randomuser.me/api/").then(res => {
      const results = res.data.results;
      this.setState({ results, loading: false });
      console.log(results);
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { results, loading } = this.state;

    if (loading) {
      return <div>loading...</div>;
    }
    if (!results) {
      return <div>data not found</div>;
    }

    return (
      <div>
        {results.map(result => {
          return (
            <div key={result.id}>
              <DataListItem result={result} />
              <MapGoogle result={result}></MapGoogle>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Data;
```

i cant passing props.result.location.coordinates.latitude and props.result.location.coordinates.longitude, but when i passing like props.result.phone, it works, and heres the code.

```
import React from "react";

export default function DataListItem(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        {props.result.name.first} {props.result.name.last}
      </div>
      <div>Developer</div>
      <div>{props.result.phone}</div>
      <div>{props.result.email}</div>
      <div>
        {props.result.location.street} {props.result.location.city}
        {props.result.location.state} {props.result.location.postcode}
      </div>
      <div>{props.result.location.coordinates.latitude}</div>
      <div>{props.result.location.coordinates.longitude}</div>
      <img src={props.result.picture.large}></img>
    </div>
  );
}
```

thanks

Comment: Initial render, `results` is empty .

Comment: no, its not empty because i can pass data such as name, phone, email, etc. the problem is i cant pass data to lat and lng from <googlemap defaultcenter>

Comment: Try commenting out `Axios.get()` inside `componentDidMount()` and see what happens with your `results.map(...)`.

Comment: data not showing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because your `result.location` object isn't there. I'm not familiar with the `react-google-maps` library but from what I can tell, you are not passing props to `Goomap`.

Try:

```
// replace this line
const WrappedMap = withScriptjs(withGoogleMap(Goomap));
// with this
const WrappedMap = withScriptjs(withGoogleMap(props => <Goomap {...props}/>));
```

Also you will need to use `parseFloat()` method for your `lat` `lng`

```
 defaultCenter={{
       lat: parseFloat(props.result.location.coordinates.latitude),
       lng: parseFloat(props.result.location.coordinates.longitude)
     }}
```

Working example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-diffie-9d5b3

Comment: Just added an example. Check it out @SteFandy

Comment: so putting props like that inside const mapgoogle really works. thanks, very helpful